# Magento Commerce 2.3 remove register-link B2B in layout.xml

Tags: layout, customer-account, luma-theme, magento-2-commerce, magento2-b2b

In my **B2C store** I removed the `register-link` in my theme.

I achieved this removing it in the Magento_Theme `default.xml` with the following directive: `<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />`

In my **B2B store** I use the same directive in my `default.xml` but it does not work. There it still shows the register link in the frontend.

Perhaps the `register-link` is different here because you can create also a company account and not "just" a personal account.

[image]

Can anybody tell **how to remove the register-link for B2B**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways in order to delete this link.

1. disable the allow_company_registration in the config by putting `company/general/allow_company_registration` to 0 (not recommended if you want this feature to be still active)
2. Magento_Company/layout/default.xml with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="register.company.link" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

The second option will just delete the link for the register links dropdown but the feature will still be active on your website.

Comment: Thanks, adding this remove directive did the trick!